# Fixing the pattern when animating with cairo

Tags: image, animation, cairo, gtk2

I'm animating a text filled with a pattern with Cairo. The problem is that when the text is moved also the pattern is "moved". How can I keep the pattern fixed inside the characters of the text? Please see the two screenshot attached.

```
if (pattern_filename)
    {
        cairo_surface_t  *tmp_surf;
        cairo_pattern_t  *font_pattern;

        tmp_surf = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png(pattern_filename);
        font_pattern = cairo_pattern_create_for_surface(tmp_surf);
        cairo_pattern_set_extend (font_pattern, CAIRO_EXTEND_REPEAT);

        cairo_set_source(cr, font_pattern);
    }
    else
    {
        /* Draw the subtitle */
        /* Set source color */
        cairo_set_source_rgba( cr, font_color[0],
                                font_color[1],
                                font_color[2],
                                font_color[3] );
    }
    /* Move to proper place and paint text */
    cairo_move_to( cr, posx, posy );
    pango_cairo_show_layout( cr, layout );
```

Thanks

[animation end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMVqt.png)
[animation start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0IXO.png)

Answer (score 0):

By default, a surface pattern puts (0,0) of the source surface at (0,0) of the target surface. To change this, you can use `cairo_set_source_surface` to directly set the surface as a pattern with some given offset. Or, you can explicitly use a pattern as you do in your code and set some translation matrix with `cairo_matrix_init_translate` and `cairo_pattern_set_matrix`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I see it just now, I'm new to this site.